# С++, ссылки и динамический полиморфизм

Tags: c++, ссылки, полиморфизм

Скажите, пожалуйста, в каком месте `Стандарта` написано то, что ссылки (наравне с указателями) могут использоваться при динамическом полиморфизме для доступа к объекту производного класса?

```
B b;
A& a = b;
```

Comment: Если в этом примере `B` наследует от `A`, то `а` может использоваться для доступа к объекту базового класса, который является подобъектом производного класса.

Comment: @user7860670, я понимаю, но я хочу найти в `Стандарте` точное описание этого.

Comment: не знаю почему в стандарте  должно быть написано об азбуке языка...  Если указываем, равно ссылаемся, если ссылаемся, равно указываем _ это и  в повседневной жизни верно...

Comment: Ну тогда вам надо читать разделы про объектную модель, время жизни, инициализацию и категории выражений. @ARHovsepyan в стандарте об "азбуке языка" написано аж 12 глав из 32

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что в стандарте прямым текстом про ссылки не написано. Дело ведь не в указателях и ссылках, а в том, что выражение `a` (или какое-нибудь `*a_ptr`) *ссылается на* полиморфный базовый класс внутри объекта `B`. А уж что это за выражение - не так важно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я так и не понял, позволено ли использовать ссылки для динамического полиморфизма или нет?

Comment: Да, можно использовать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, есть ссылка на точное место стандарта, где об этом сказано?

Comment: В продолжение коммента выше: Вот я открыл [`[expr.call]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#3): *"[If the selected function is virtual] its final overrider in the dynamic type of the object expression is called; such a call is referred to as a virtual function call."* Видите, про указатели и ссылки ни слова. Упоминается только динамический тип выражения. В определении "динамического типа" ([`[defns.dynamic.type]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.dynamic.type)) тоже ничего нет про указатели и ссылки: [1/2]

Comment: *"[for a glvalue, the dynamic type is a] type of the most derived object ([intro.object]) to which the glvalue refers"*. И ссылка, и разыменованный указатель являются glvalue, поэтому полиморфизм должен работать в обоих случаях. [2/2]